# <option> ele dynamically added in directive's link function not firing parent select's ngChange

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I need to add `<option>` elements dynamically based on certain property values of the source data populating the dropdown list. Sometimes the  child elements need to instead be `<optgroup>` elements due to the crazy way marketing wants data displayed. Due to the requirements, I cannot do simple  statements with ng-options nor can I do a parent `<select>` with a child  element combined with ng-repeat. I run into various issues in my directive trying to use ng-switch or ng-if to get the desired result.

Because of those issues I decided to put the entire select element as the template in my directive. Then in the link function I would parse out all the incoming data and append the correctly formatted `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements to the parent `<select>` defined in the template. I started with the scaled down code in my directive below and was going to expand upon it with my conditional logic when I noticed changing the selected option in the UI was not firing the parent select's ng-change function in my controller. The ng-change does fire when I let Angular add all the options itself with ng-options or when I use child option element with ng-repeat. However, breaking it out the way shown below with a minimal parent defined in the template and then dynamically adding child elements in link does not work.

```
app.directive('fullSelect', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { datarepo: "=datarepo" },
        replace: true,
        template: "<select class='col-xs-8' id='gridStyle' " + 
                    'ng-model="vm.gridStyle" ng-change="vm.gridStyleUpdated()"></select>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.forEach(scope.datarepo, function (value, key) {
                var opt = angular.element('<option value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');
                element.append($compile(opt)(scope));
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I additionally tried adding an ng-click to each of the newly added `<option>` elements during the forEach loop, but even those do not fire. I assume this is all some sort of scope/visibility issue.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: I'm not really sure this makes sense.  They want you to use `<optgroup>` elements instead of `<option>` elements in order to display the data differently? you can't select an `<optgroup>` item, so it sounds like you aren't even structuring your data correctly in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @Claies but eventually there will be a mix of both option and optgroup elements in the dropdown. For example the first two items may be option elements that are selectable. The next "option" will instead be an optgroup and that will have other selectable option elements. I will toggle between outputting option or optgroup elements based upon set property values for each incoming element in an object array. I can get all that going. The problem I am trying to overcome here is to get option elements that are added in the forEach to fire the parent select's ng-change.

Comment: you would be better off breaking your groups into their own array, adding an indexer for the group to each item, and using the `group by` parameter for `ng-options`. since that generates `<optgroup>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.vm = {};
                    scope.vm.gridStyleUpdated = function () {
                        console.log("changed");
                    }
                    angular.forEach(scope.datarepo, function (value, key) {
                        var opt = angular.element('<option value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');
                        element.append($compile(opt)(scope));
                    });
                }
```

Comment: Thanks @TomerKeisar That does cause the function to fire in the directive where it is defined. I was trying to get it to fire in the main controller vm.gridStyleChanged funciton though.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got what I wanted by breaking up my directive a little and putting a big chunk of it back into the html view. Now the events are correctly firing and I also get additional benefit of nested option and optgroup elements to any level which is something that started this whole cycle. Here is what the view html looks like now:

```
        <fieldset id="fs_gridStyle">
            <label class="col-xs-4" for="gridStyle">Grid Style *</label>
            <select class="col-xs-8" id="gridStyle"
                    ng-model="vm.gridStyle"
                    ng-change="vm.gridStyleUpdated()"
                    full-select datarepo="vm.gridStyles">
            </select>
        </fieldset>
```

And here is what the directive looks like:

```
app.directive('fullSelect', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: { datarepo: "=datarepo" },
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            angular.forEach(scope.datarepo, function (value, key) {
                var opt;
                var display = "";
                for (var idx = 0; idx < value.level; idx++) {
                    display += "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                }
                display += value.label;
                if (value.type === "Option") {
                    opt = angular.element('<option value="' + value.value + '">' + display + '</option>');
                }
                else {
                    opt = angular.element('<optgroup label="' + display + '"></optgroup>');
                }
                element.append($compile(opt)(scope));
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Now I just need to make sure it performs properly, but so far it looks good. It gives me my desired end result where my incoming object array contains values, labels and misc info such as a level property to indicate where that item should be indented within the dropdown list, etc. I can now have any number of option and optgroup children embedded within the dropdown list indented as needed. You cannot nest multiple optgroup elements, but I visually handle that with the level property which adds   spaces to the text.